# JWT Authentication strategy

Tags: go, jwt

Right now I have this confusion whether I should store JWT Token in the session or not

Should I

1. Store it in Redis after Token creation has been made

   ```
   // JWT TOKEN
   token := CreateToken(user)   

   // Storing it in Gorilla Session + Redis     
   s := sessions.Default(c)
   s.Set("token", token)
   s.Save()
   ```

So then take the token from the server instead from subsequent request from the request Header

```
    s.Get("token")
    // and to something with it
```

2. Pass the Token in Subsequent request so in every route that required The token

   ```
   func login(c *gin.Context) {
       c.Getheader("Authorization")
   }
   ```

I'm using gin framework

Which approach is better session or subsequent request from user

Regards,
Naufal

Comment: If you have sessions - you don't need JWT.

Answer (score 3):

If you make a **client** - then YES, as you've obtained the a token, you should store it and pass with subsequent requests.

If you make a **server** - then NO. You have no need to store a token you've issued, but you should validate it any time you get with a client's request. This way you can make your service stateless and more scalable.

Answer (score 1):

> Don't store JWT in sessions.

One important benefits of using JWT is keeping server stateless. Now, If you put JWT in sessions, you are losing the benefits of JWT.

**Example:**

Say, you have two instances of your server load-balanced. Unless you create some sort of shared session storage, your visitor will have to be forced to visit the same server every time (and that is not easy).